# GDI+ gradient effect

Tags: c#, gdi+

In the code below:

```
void f13(Graphics g)
{
  g.FillRectangle(new SolidBrush(Color.Black), pictureBox1.ClientRectangle);
  g.InterpolationMode = InterpolationMode.HighQualityBicubic;
  var zf = .0143;
  const int w = 6000, h = 10, margin = 40;
  var bmp = new Bitmap(w + 2 * margin, h + 2 * margin);
  var bmpG = Graphics.FromImage(bmp);
  bmpG.FillRectangle(new SolidBrush(Color.White), 0, 0, bmp.Width, bmp.Height);

  var srcRect = new RectangleF(margin - .5f, margin - .5f, w, h);
  zf = (float)Convert.ToInt32(w * zf) / w;
  var destRect = new Rectangle(0, 0, Convert.ToInt32(w * zf), Convert.ToInt32(w * zf));
  g.DrawImage(bmp, destRect, srcRect, GraphicsUnit.Pixel);
  destRect.X += destRect.Width;
  g.DrawImage(bmp, destRect, srcRect, GraphicsUnit.Pixel);
}

private void pictureBox1_Paint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
{
  f13(e.Graphics);
}
```

I get a gap between two rectangles:

[micro http://www.uploadup.com/di-0HXM.png](http://www.uploadup.com/di-0HXM.png)
[macro http://www.uploadup.com/di-G1O5.png](http://www.uploadup.com/di-G1O5.png)

why is that?

If the gap line is not so clear, you may decrease margin. if you set it to 10 you'll get:

[macro, less margin http://www.uploadup.com/di-P2ZT.png](http://www.uploadup.com/di-P2ZT.png)

Comment: Add `g.PixelOffsetMode = PixelOffsetMode.Half;` so floating point round-off error doesn't byte.

Comment: thanks Hans,
this decreased the value of margin to 9. now even with 8 the gap appears. i still can explain this and couldn't figure out what's the PixelOffsetMode. would u explain more?

Comment: i also commented the line which sets the interpolation mode and this caused the margin to have to increase. with the default interpolation mode the margin must be at least 18. what's happening in GDI+ and how can i find my way within it?

Answer (score 1):

That'll happen if your rectangles' boundaries aren't integers. Gradient has nothing to do with it.

Consider: Let's say you're drawing a rectangle whose right side is at X=100.5, and you're filling it with white (with the existing background being black). So the graphics library (this isn't specific to GDI+) will "half-fill" those rightmost pixels (at X=100) with white, meaning they blend the existing black with a 50% mix of white, for a result of gray.

Then you draw another rectangle whose left side is at X=100.5. Now you're once again filling the pixels at X=100 halfway with white, so the graphics library will take the existing color (gray) and blend it with a 50% white, leaving you with 75% white.

If you don't want this kind of seam, you have to either (a) make sure your rectangles overlap a little bit, or (b) manually round your coordinates to the nearest pixel, so all the pixels are getting completely written instead of blended with what's already there.

Comment: thank u for replying. consider drawing only one rectangle. if i draw it so that it doesn't produce any gray scale so drawing two rectangles produces no gap effect, right? so let's simplify the problem to:
how can i draw an image from a source rectangle of it which is not integral to a destination rectangle which is integral so that no gray scale effect appears?
as Vincent informed [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/10115502/1137082) (0, 0) of the source image defines at where we call (.5, .5) of it. so the image begins from (-.5, -.5). i expect in the code above when i define margin as...

Comment: ... one pixel, and begin my source rectangle from (.5, .5), one pixel around the source rectangle be enough to omit the gray effect. in another words, i didn't start my source rectangle just from the source image edges. indeed there's one pixel margin around it with the same color (white). when i saw that this one pixel is not enough i increased it. but i see that i must use a thick margin to be enough. whay is that? this is my question.

Comment: and about your suggestions:
a. i prefer not to overlap them. besides, i don't know how much they must overlap to be enough.
b. source rectangle can't be at integral boundaries. consider when i choose a 2x2 shape and want to scroll it in a 3000x3000 pixel client area.